# Can an unmarried Brahmin man cook and clean for himself?

Tags: brahmins, varna

Can an unmarried brahmin man who lives alone cook, clean, wash clothes for himself ?
Or he must employ someone else to these things for him.

Is it demeaning to his Varna ? Or Is it okay ?

Comment: all brahmin men know how to cook because they have to when their wife is in menses (if mom is not living with them). they also clean their own dhotis. all temple cooks are brahmin men.